# change level 1 column index names to string

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe with multiindex columns.  The column names are:

```
H1                             H2                           H3                     
 0      1       2       3       0      1      2       3      0      1      2      3
```

I want to merge the names, but the level0 names are str format and the level1 names are int format.

When I try to join with:

```
wide_df.columns = wide_df.columns.levels[1].astype(str)
wide_df.columns = ['_'.join(col) for col in wide_df.columns.values]
wide_df.columns = pd.Index(wide_df.columns)
```

I get:

````
```ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 12 elements, new values have 4 elements```
````

If I get rid of this line:

````
```wide_df.columns = wide_df.columns.levels[1].astype(str)```
````

Then I get this:

````
```TypeError: sequence item 1: expected str instance, int found```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just re-create it

```
s= wide_df.columns 
idx=pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([s.get_level_values(0),s.get_level_values(1).astype(str)])

wide_df.columns=idx
```

Also , If you just want the columns being flatten

```
wide_df.columns = wide_df.columns.map('{0[0]}_{0[1]}'.format)
```